# Switch Apple ID From Gmail To iCloud On Recently Created Computer

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-id

I recently bought a computer less than 1 month ago and created a new Apple ID. I set the email of the Apple ID to a Gmail address but later created an iCloud address. I'm trying to change the email of the Apple ID to the iCloud email but it says "This email address cannot be used as an Apple ID at this time." Do I have to wait?

Answer (score 3):

Per [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/109353), you cannot change it within 30 days of setting up your @icloud.com address.

> #### If you can't change your Apple ID
>
> If you try to change your Apple ID to an @icloud.com email address that was created within the last 30 days, you will be asked to try again later.
>
> If you see a message that the email address you want to use isn't available or is already in use, check that you or a family member aren't already using that email address with a different Apple ID. If a family member is using that email address, remove it from their account, then try to use it.

So, to answer your question, yes, you’ll have to wait.